# Functorial Morphism in Top / Topological Question

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

Is there any natural function which assignes to any function $f:X\to X$ a function $\epsilon_{\tau}(f):X\to X$ which is continuous in the topological space $(X,\tau)$?

Comment: Hmm, that's a very general question. Suppose $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\tau$ is the standard topology. Consider the function $f$ that is $0$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $1$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. What continuous function would you assign to $f$? (Probably the zero function, but then you are actually talking about measures and stuff which you can't use in general). How about a function with an essential discontinuity, how would you resolve this? You can obviously define $\varepsilon(f)=\text{Id}_X$ for all $f:X\rightarrow X$, but that's not what you are looking for.

Comment: I need this function to define the co-unity in showing that the forgetful functor from $\mathbf{Top}$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ admits a left adjoint given by the discrete topology...

Comment: No you don't. Why would you think that ?

Comment: In discrete topology every function is continous. So there is actually not much to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your Functor from $\mathbf{Set}$ to $\mathbf{Top}$. You send any object in $\mathbf{Set}$ to itself equipped with the discrete topology. Now any function between topological spaces where the domain is equipped with the discrete topology is continous. Why? Because every subset is open in the discrete topology. So $f^{-1}(U)$ will always be open for any open $U$. So you can just send $f$ to itself.